# Is there any good open source software for Security Risk Analysis? 

Tags: security-theater

Is there any good open source software for Security Risk Analysis?

for example something like one explained on : http://www.security-risk-analysis.com/introduction.htm

Comment: I'm sorry, it is not clear what you are asking. I think it has lost something in translation. You might try editing the question.

Comment: If you are worried about using a weak password the solution is really simple.  **Don't use weak passwords**

Comment: That's much clearer, thanks. Next question: what sort of risk analysis methodology do you use? There are many different approaches, and each one has different requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Security risk analysis requires intelligence, understanding of security concepts, knowledge of the application domain, and experience with security.  It's not something you can automate with a tool.  There is no substitute for having an experienced security expert understand your application domain and perform a security risk analysis.

(Of course, there may be opportunities for a security expert to use tools to help him/her with the analysis.  But the tool is not a replacement for a human expert.  A tool cannot perform a security risk analysis on its own.)

Answer (score 1):

As risk analysis and threat modeling are closely related IMO, I think you should give Threat Modeler a try. Free and works great for me :)

http://www.myappsecurity.com/threatmodeler/